# Как добавить сбор Allure отчетов при запуске тестов из jar с помощью junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.2.jar

Tags: allure

У нас на проекте тесты запускаются из jar.
Тесты написаны на kotlin c Junit5, проект собирается в jar командой mvn clean package.
После сборки тесты запускаются командой:
`java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.2.jar -cp 1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-tests.jar --select-package com.example.tests`

Необходимо, чтобы при таком запуске собирался allure-results.
Что нужно прописать в команде, чтобы allure-отчет собирался?